# How to NOT call Font Awesome or font icons in WordPress

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I have a theme that makes use of Font Awesome icons by default. I have replaced all of them with custom .png icons using CSS. However, on web page load, the font-awesome icons takes up a size or bandwidth of 55.8 kb which is not good for page speed. How do I prevent an http request for Font Awesome icons altogether? I tried renaming and deleting the Font Awesome folder of the theme but the http request is still being made although it's unclear if its still taking up the same aforementioned bandwidth but I would like to prevent the request anyway. I have the following lines in my `functions.php`:

```
function myTheme_load_style() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'myTheme_googleFonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,400italic,700italic|Merriweather:700,900,400italic' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'myTheme_fontawesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fa/css/font-awesome.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'myTheme_style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    }
}
```

Would modifying the above lines help? If yes, how? If no, how do I, then?

Comment: Remove or comment out the second `wp_enqueue_style` line.

Comment: @ialocin I use a child theme with its own functions.php. There are only a few lines of php that I added on my own. The rest are inherited from the parents. How do I remove what you asked me to remove, in the child theme, without altering the parent's files?

Comment: As @Bruno said, use [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style). Next time please add relevant information, like the use of a child theme to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to find how your theme is calling the styles. If with enqueue, you can use the `wp_dequeue_style()` on your child theme, if directly in header/footer, you will need to copy those to your child theme and remove those calls.

Comment: could you be more detailed, please?

Comment: You will have to search through the main theme files for `wp_enqueue_style` . This way you will be able to check the handler of that specific font to use the `wp_dequeue_style()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style